# Resume from suspend does not work on ASUS K501UX running Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: suspend, laptop, power-management, 16.10

When my laptop goes to sleep either when it's inactive for a period of time or I click the suspend option in the power menu, I am unable to resume from suspend. It comes back up with a blank black backlit screen, and I can't even switch to a different tty and get a login shell. I have to hold the power button in to hard reset the system. Please help me fix this. I am tired of losing data from this bug.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same Bug, I need to reboot manually my laptop after it enter in Stand-by mode.

I got an Asus K501UQ. 
I meet this bug after I switch my Graphic driver to Nvidia GeForce 940MX/PCIe/SSE2 and update Ubuntu 16.10.

Nvidia drivers
**Known Issues with this release:**
* Resuming from suspend may not be reliable on GeForce GTX 9xx boards in some configurations.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.